# What is better? Login with Phone or Email or Both?

Tags: mobile-application, login, registration

We are developing a mobile app, which our customer requested the following login/registration options.

> Email, Gmail, Apple, Phone

In addition to that, customer want the user to try the app before they register.

Our UI/UX designers are not very happy about this, because they say they have never seen an app using both Email/Phone and it is very hard for them to create a good user experience on this.

For an example, they say if this app is using `Email, GMail, Apple` for login, then they can create Email/Password fields and place Gmail, Apple icons below this. But when the phone number comes in, they question me where on earth they can place it without creating a bad experience.

However customer is strict with his Phone login requirement. But if this "really" should not be done, I can convince him.

This is a Freelancing app.

I am looking for your advice on this, whether this `Email, Gmail, Apple, Phone` approach is good or we should remove phone or email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UI/UX designers are on the right track with placing the SSO buttons outside of the main login.

To add mobile and keep the UI from getting too cluttered, you could move the Password field to the next step (like Google does today).

[image: Login UI that supports email, mobile, and SSO]

If the user enters a phone number, they wouldn't go to the Password step; they'd instead see a step to enter the code that was sent by SMS, or however you plan to complete the authentication.

Comment: wow! Fascinating! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider these factors:

1. Some people do not have a phone number.
2. Some people do not have a phone number in your country.
3. Some people can't access their phone at the moment (travel, reception).
4. Some people never reveal their phone number to strangers. Filtering email spam is easier than filtering phone spam.

In [one study](https://vtldesign.com/web-strategy/conversion-rate-optimization/phone-number-form-field-case-study/), asking for a phone number halved the conversion rate.

Comment: Most humans don’t have email addresses (or know how to use them), and most humans do have phone. Email usage is likely to decline while smartphone usage to increase.

Comment: This addresses none of those four points. Just because your user HAS a phone number does not mean they can or want to give it to you at the moment. Email usually works better (see research linked above) but it comes down to who your target demographic is.